# I just want to run a simple app in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a docker image that serves a simple static web page. 
I have a working Kubernetes cluster of 4 nodes (physical servers not in the cloud anywhere).

I want to run that docker image on 2 of the 4 Kubernetes nodes and have it be accessible to the world outside the cluster and load balanced and have it move it to another node if one dies.

Do I need to make a pod then a replication controller then a kube proxy something?
Or do I need to just make a replication controller and expose it somehow? 
Do I need to make service?

I don't need help with how to make any of those things, that seems well documented, but what I can't tell what I need to make.

Comment: One way to do this would be: a deployment to manage your instances, and a service in front of it to expose it to the outside world.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to **expose** your **service** (that consists of **pods** which are run/scaled/restarted by your **replication controller**). Using **deployment** instead of replication controller has additional benefits (mainly for updating the app).

If you are on bare metal then you probably wish to expose your service via `type: NodePort` - so every node in your cluster will open a static port that routes traffic to pods.

You can then either point your load balancer to that nodes on that port, or make a DNS entry with all Kubernetes nodes.

Docs: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/quick-start/

Comment: So forget replication controller the steps go like:
Create Deployment ->
Create Service ->
Expose Service ->
Then put what IP address in DNS? 
 And that will give me load balancing and fail over?

Comment: Put the ip of the EXTERNAL loadbalancer in the DNS. Point the loadbalancer to the ip-addresses of all the k8s nodes.

Comment: Any suggestions as to what to use for an external loadbalancer? And it couldn't point to all the nodes of the cluster, only 2 of them are running the app and what if one of them goes down?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need:

1) A load balancer on one of your nodes in your cluster, that is a reverse proxy Pod like `nginx` to proxy the traffic to an `upstream`.

This Pod will need to be exposed to the outside using `hostPort` like

```
ports:
- containerPort: 80
  hostPort: 80
  name: http
- containerPort: 443
  hostPort: 443
  name: https
```

2) A **Service** that will use the web server selector as target.

3) Set the Service name (which will resolve to the Service IP) as the upstream in nginx config

4) Deploy your web server Pods, which will have the selector to be targeted by the Service.

You might also want to look at External IP for the Service 
http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#external-ips

but I personally never managed to get that working on my bare metal cluster.